# Why do these two functions have a different type?

Tags: haskell, types

I have two functions

```
(\f b -> (\a -> a) f b b)
```

and

```
(\f b -> (\a -> 0) f b b)
```

I tried to find the type of these functions by hand and got

```
(t1 -> t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t2
```

and

```
Num t3 => (t1 -> t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t3
```

But when I use GHCI to get the type using `:t` I get the following

```
(\f b -> (\a -> a) f b b) :: (t1 -> t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t2
(\f b -> (\a -> 0) f b b) :: Num (t1 -> t1 -> t2) => p -> t1 -> t2
```

I don't understand how changing `\a -> a` to `\a -> 0` changes the first parameter from `(t1 -> t1 -> t2)` to `p`

Comment: Because your function `\a -> 0` returns a *number*, whereas for `\a -> a`, it returns the parameter, so the output is the same as the input type.

Comment: What would you expect to happen? You're specifying a return type, i.e. a number, so of course the type is going to change! What *specifically* confuses you?

Comment: Sure, but why is the first parameter now `p` instead of  `(t1 -> t1 -> t2)`

Comment: @joelfischerr: because the first parameter is `f` (in `\f b -> ...`), and `f` thus is a free parameter, since we use it as an argument for `(\a -> 0)`, which means that regardless what we write, it is "ignored".

Comment: and it's ignored because of Haskells lazy evaluation or would it work the same way with eager evaluation?

Comment: Typing is independent of evaluation strategy.

Comment: But if f b b was evaluated before it was substituted into \a -> b, it would need a more specific type wouldn't it?

Comment: `f b b` is not a subexpression in your code. Function application is left associative, so it parses as `(((\a -> 0) f) b) b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Deriving the type for `(\f b -> (\a -> a) f b b)`

Well let us try to derive the type for the expression:

```
(\f b -> (\a -> a) f b b)
```

or more verbose:

```
(\f -> (\b -> (((\a -> a) f) b) b))
```

We here see that this is a function taking two parameters (well technically speaking a function always takes one parameter, and the result of that function then can take another one, but let us assume that if we talk about "two parameters", we mean such construct).

The parameters are thus `f`, and `b`, and initially we do not know much about these, so we assign them a type, and the expression is:

```
f :: g
b :: h
(\f b -> (\a -> a) f b b) :: g -> (h -> i)
```

We thus create three types `g`, `h` and `i` (I here used other identifiers than `a`, `b` and `c`, since that could introduce confusion with the variables).

But we are not done yet, since the expression itself, can introduce more constraints on how the types behave. We see for example a lambda expression: `\a -> a`, this clearly has as type:

```
\a -> a :: j -> j
```

Next we see a function application, with `\a -> a` as function, and `f` as argument, so that means that `g ~ j` (`g` and `j` are the same type), and the type of `(\a -> a) f` is `(\a -> a) f :: g`.

But we are not done yet, since the result of `(\a -> a) f`, now acts as a function in a function application with `b`, so that means that `g` is in fact a function, with input type `h`, and some (currently unknown output type), so:

```
g ~ (h -> k)
```

So the type of `(\a -> a) f b` is `k`, but again we are not done yet, since we perform another function application with `(\a -> a) f b` as function (type `k`), and `b` as parameter, so that means that `k` is in fact a function, with `h` as parameter type, and the result is the type of the expression, so `i`. So that means we have:

```
g ~ j
g ~ (h -> k)
k ~ (h -> i)
```

In other words, the type of the expression is:

```
(\f b -> (\a -> a) f b b) :: (h -> (h -> i)) -> (h -> i)
```

or less verbose:

```
(\f b -> (\a -> a) f b b) :: (h -> h -> i) -> h -> i
```

## Deriving the type for `(\f b -> (\a -> 0) f b b)`

The first steps of the derivation are more or less the same, we first introduce some type variables:

```
f :: g
b :: h
(\f b -> (\a -> 0) f b b) :: g -> (h -> i)
```

and now we start doing the inference. We first infer the type of `(\a -> 0)`. This is a function, with type `Num l => j -> l` since `0` is a `Num`ber, but it can be any `Num` type, and has nothing to do with the type of the parameter `a`.

Next we see that there is a function call with `(\a -> 0)` as function, and `f` as parameter, we thus conclude that `g ~ j`. The type of the result of this function call is `(\a -> 0) f :: Num l => l`.

Now we see another function call with `(\a -> 0) f` as function, and `b` as parameter. We thus conclude that `l` is a function (so `l ~ (h -> k)`).

The last function call is with `(\a -> 0) f b :: k` as function, and `b` again as parameter. This means that `k` is a function `k ~ h -> i`. We thus obtain the following types and equalities:

```
f :: g
b :: h
(\a -> 0) :: Num l => j -> l
(\f b -> (\a -> 0) f b b) :: g -> (h -> i)
g ~ j
l ~ (h -> k)
k ~ (h -> i)
```

The type of the expression is thus:

```
(\f b -> (\a -> 0) f b b) :: g -> (h -> i)
```

or more specific:

```
(\f b -> (\a -> 0) f b b) :: Num (h -> (h -> i)) => g -> (h -> i)
```

or less verbose:

```
(\f b -> (\a -> 0) f b b) :: Num (h -> h -> i) => g -> h -> i
```

So since we use as inner lambda expression `(\a -> 0)`, nor the *type* nor the *value* of `f`, are relevant anymore. `(\a -> 0) f` will always return `0`, and this should be a function, that can take a `b` into account.

At least from a theoretical point of view, there is nothing "strange" about a function that is a `Num` (as long as it supports the functions that should be implemented by `Num` types). We could for example implement a function `instance Num (a -> b -> Int)`, and thus see `0` as a *constant* function that always maps to `0`, and `(+)` as a way to construct a new function that adds the two functions together.